# How to identify if user has clicked "Clone with Related" on opportunity record page?

Tags: clone

Requirement is to auto-populated the 'opportunity source' field if opportunity is created using "Clone with Related" button.

- Current functionality is

1. 'opportunity source' is populated with 'Referral' if lead is converted.
2. If New opportunity is created using new button the 'opportunity source' is populated with 'Self-Generated'

Challenge is to find out if clone button is clicked and opportunity is created using 'clone with Related' and then populate the 'opportunity source' with 'Self-Generated'

I have tried setting the default value of opportunity source to 'Self -Generated' however cloning opportunity is override with exisiting value.